# Using fetch results as function parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have fetchTeam(teamName) function which gets an array of players and displays them in HTML. and another function that takes a player name as a parameter and displays the player stats. Something like this....

```
let result = document.getElementById("result");
let teamName;

const fetchTeam = async (teamName) => {
  teamName = document.getElementById("teamName").value;
  const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/${teamName}`);
  const data = await response.json();
  let team = data.teamStats;
  let players = data.playerStats;
  const teamName = team[0].Name;
  const logo = team[0].Logo;
  const WL = team[0].WL;

  result.innerHTML = `

<br><div class="top">
<h3>${teamName}</h3>
<h4>Win / Loss: ${WL}</h4>
<img src=${logo}></div>
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="flex-child">
<button class='name' onclick="fetchPlayer("${players[0][0].Player}")> ${players[0][0].Player} </button> ...
`
```

That all works fine except the onclick fetchPlayer function at the bottom.... Heres the code for that:

```
const results = document.getElementById("results");

const fetchPlayer = async (player) => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://get-player.herokuapp.com/${player}`);
  const data = await response.json();

results.innerHTML = `
<br>
<div class="layout">
        <div class="child"><img src="${data.sprite}[0]"><br>${data.mons[0]}</div>
`
```

As you can see, i want to display the team members and then clicking on a member name will show their stats.

edit: format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

First, you redeclare `teamName` in your `fetchTeam` function. That cannot work.

```js
const fetchTeam = async (teamName) => {
  teamName = document.getElementById("teamName").value;
  ...
  const teamName = team[0].Name;
}
```

Second, your button syntax is incorrect :
`<button class='name' onclick="fetchPlayer("${players[0][0].Player}")>`
should be
`<button class='name' onclick="fetchPlayer('${players[0][0].Player}')">`

Third, as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68150267/9310651), in your `fetchPlayer` function
`<img src="${data.sprite}[0]">` should be `<img src="${data.sprite[0]}">`

Comment: For some reason the function didn't work when i first declared teamName inside of it, only after i declared it outside then change it's value from within the function. 

Just changed the button syntax and that fixed it! Why is it always something so simple. Haha, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the `fetchPlayer` function,

Change `<img src="${data.sprite}[0]">` to `<img src="${data.sprite[0]}">`